# Notation about which I don't fully understand

Tags: calculus, limits

What is the meaning behind writting $$\lim_{x\rightarrow a}e^{f(x)}=e^{\lim{x\rightarrow a}f(x)}$$ Has it something to do with continuity of the exponential? If so, if we had a limit like the following $$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\Bigg[\Big(1+\frac{1}{x}\Big)^x\Bigg]^{f(x)}$$

does this property explain why we can evaluate a $1^{\infty}$-limit "by parts", by first seeing that $$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\Big(1+\frac{1}{x}\Big)^x=e$$ and that $$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}f(x)=L$$ and so we can deduce that $$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\Bigg[\Big(1+\frac{1}{x}\Big)^x\Bigg]^{f(x)}=e^L$$

Comment: Yes its the continuity of the exponential. No you cannot assign a value to $1^\infty$. Be careful $e^x$ has no intrinsic meaning and must be read $\exp(x)$.

Comment: @blamethelag: *Be careful* $e^x$ *has no intrinsic meaning and must be read* $\exp(x)$ --- Could you explain this further? The notations $e^x$ and $\exp(x)$ generally mean the same thing, and if not, it's due to a certain locally defined (i.e. author/book specific) meaning that is not in evidence here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this answer I try to address the question of the OP and the question of Dave.

In the OP's question it is written
$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow a} e^{f(x)} = e^{\lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x)}
$$
and from this I infer that $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x)$ is well defined as a real (maybe $\pm \infty$ if you wish) number. Then the fact that the above equality holds is exactly because the function $x \mapsto e^x$ is continuous. Indeed, because the exponential is continuous, whenever $f$ has a limit at $a$ by composition of limits the compound map $x \mapsto e^{f(x)}$ has a limit at $a$, and the above formula gives the expression of the limit.

Then the OP wishes to evaluate
$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \left[ \left( 1 + \frac 1 x \right)^x \right] ^{f(x)},\quad L = \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x) \in \mathbb R
$$
that is not accurately called $1^\infty$. Here it is more like $e^L$, which is wrong in general. For instance try
$$
f(x) = 1/x,\quad f(x) = 1/x^2.
$$

My comment about the notation $e^x$ is motivated by the following observation: to define the exponentiation $x^y$ we use the formula
$$
x^y = \exp(y \ln(x)).
$$
So trying to represent $e^x$ by powers is (in my opinion) always misleading because
$$
\left( 1 + \frac 1 x \right)^x := \exp \left( x \ln \left( 1 + \frac 1 x \right) \right).
$$
Said differently, if one wishes to express $e^x$ by approximating the number $e$, say by a sequence $(e_n)$, and then computing $\lim_n e_n^x$ I would say this is nonsens because computing $e_n^x$ relies on the knowledge of the function $\exp$. Moreover a more sophisticated approximation
$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \left[ \left( 1 + \frac 1 x \right)^x \right] ^{f(x)} = e^{\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x)}
$$
was proved to be wrong. Therefore I suggest that in this type of situation one may think twice before to write $e^x$. Nonetheless it is by definition that
$$
e^x = \exp(x)
$$
and with that I could not differ.

Comment: Yes, we can (and perhaps usually do) get the definition of arbitrary real powers of arbitrary positive real numbers by means of the $\exp$ function. But once we have done that, the expression $y^x$ is defined for any real $x$ and positive real $y,$ including the case where $y=e.$ Once we have established that fact, why can't we then write $e^x$ or $\exp(x)$ interchangeably afterward? In the OP I think it's reasonable to assume that we have that much of real analysis already worked out and available for use.

Comment: @DavidK This is just a matter of notations and of our understanding of them. If you know what you are doing I could not make suggestions. If you have some troubles and want to check things then I suggest to come back to $\exp$. Maybe this has nothing to do with the original question and for that I apologize.

Comment: Actually I think the answer is relevant to the question, especially where you point out the error in the OP's reinterpretation of the limit, which seems to have a lot to do with exactly the issues you discuss here.

Answer (score 0):

It is assumed that the limit of the function converges. Then you could treat it as any regular constant. Note that this works only when the limit converges.